# MySQL Encoding 4 byte in 3 byte utf-8 - Incorrect string value

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8

According to the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) which supports only up to 3 byte utf-8 unicode encoding.
My question is, how can I replace characters that require 4 byte utf-8 encoding in my database? And how do I decode those characters in order to display exactly what the user wrote?

Part of the integration test:

```
description = u'baaam á ✓ ✌ ❤'
print description
test_convention = Blog.objects.create(title="test title",
                                            description=description,
                                            login=self.user,
                                            tag=self.tag)
```

Error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
baaam á ✓ ✌ ❤
E..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_post_blog (blogs.tests.PostTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Developer/project/pro/blogs/tests.py", line 64, in test_post_blog
    tag=self.tag)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x9C\\x93 \\xE2\\x9C...' for column 'description' at row 1")

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.383s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Table's configuration:

```
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                             | Engine | Version | Collation         | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| blogs_blog                       | InnoDB |      10 | utf8_general_ci   | Compact    |   25 |           1966 |       49152 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |             35 | 2014-02-09 00:57:59 | NULL        | NULL       |     NULL |                |         |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

**Update:** I already changed the table and column configurations from utf-8 to utf8mb4 and still getting the same error, any ideas?

```
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                             | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| blogs_blog                       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    5 |           3276 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |             36 | 2014-02-17 22:24:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

and:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field         | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+---------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id            | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| title         | varchar(500) | latin1_swedish_ci  | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| description   | longtext     | utf8mb4_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| creation_date | datetime     | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| login_id      | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| tag_id        | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+---------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: why wouldn't you use 4 bytes UTF? It is utf8mb4, afair

Comment: well, I already change the collation to utf8mb4 and still not working, but is a good start, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is supported, but not as`utf8`. Add the following to the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`:

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When creating a database, use:

```
CREATE DATABASE xxxxx DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

At the end of a `CREATE TABLE` command, add:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```